# My ether was automatically sent to different address without my permission

Tags: ether, metamask

My ethereum account is 0xfAd956B56be1298ee8ec1950cc305B46268d926f (generated by metamask) and the moment friend of mine sent me an ether, it was automatically directed to another account. This is the transaction hash

0xd451bee48418fff2e728d321e2c62a1bd2f38dd21788621395f72a7ad371de0f

What is the issue here? I am just utterly confused.

Comment: Your friend has sent to you 0.125 ether, and less then 10% of that was transferred to another account, which kinda looks like a fee taken by whatever application you're using. I agree that the fact that this application can take such fee to begin with (even a fair fee for that matter) is something to worry about, because it means that this application holds the private key of your account, which is therefore compromised to a certain degree (for example, how much do you trust the security level of this application's DB?).

Comment: There seem to be other transactions to the same wallet (0x7BFb08454aE23bA16bfdfd8a9F541a1427941576), which follow a similar pattern (though I noticed that in most cases the fee is only around 1% or so).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the owner of the account that took your eth is running scripts to send money to his or her self. Others have also had this problem and commented on etherscan as seen in the image below. An attacker can do this if an accounts is unlocked or has a compromised private keys.

This could also have resulted from your private key being compromised - either from metamask or from wherever you stored your wallet backup (cloud / email) / local computer).

Two items that could have resulted in this if you are coding or working with the geth console would be an unprotected RPC port with unlocked accounts or the use of `personal.account.unlock`

Initially looking at the transfer - only a small amount of value was transferred to this other account (`10%` of the initial transaction), but the gas price is set extremely high making the transaction fee take up the other 90% of the initial transaction, clearing out the account balance.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that your account has been compromised. There are malicious actors whose goal is to steal private keys, monitor the blockchain for when those accounts are transferred some Ether and immediately transfer it one of their accounts.

MetaMask is not a bad wallet, just make sure you don't backup your mnemonic on a device with access to Internet. For maximum security though, you may want to get hold of a [Ledger](https://www.ledger.com/) or a [Trezor](https://trezor.io/).